# When an I print out an array How do I make it listed?

Tags: javascript, arrays

When I go to print out an array, That may have items put into it at later times, like this:

```
var ArrayEx = ['Zero'];

ArrayEx.push('One');

ArrayEx.push('Two');

alert(ArrayEx);

//or

document.write(ArrayEx);
```

It usually just prints it all out in one big blob of text. I was wondering, if I make it print in the alert box or the document, how i can make it a list, going down, or just with a  `,` in between each one. Does anyone know how I could do that?

Comment: console.log(ArrayEx);

Comment: `alert(ArrayEx)` also prints the values with a comma in between them. Could you give an example of where it doesn't do so?

Answer (score 1):

```
var ArrayEx = ['Zero'];

ArrayEx.push('One');

ArrayEx.push('Two');

var joined = ArrayEx.join(", ");

console.log(joined);
```

This will log

"Zero, One, Two"

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick and simple way to loop through an array and list the items in the array:

http://jsfiddle.net/mjgbm6c3/

**HTML**

```
<ul class="sample-list"></ul>
```

**JS**

```
var ArrayEx = ['Zero'];

ArrayEx.push('One');

ArrayEx.push('Two');

    for(var i = 0; i < ArrayEx.length; i++){
        var item = '<li>' + ArrayEx[i] + '</li>';
        $('.sample-list').append(item);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Array.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method, it will build a string out of the elements in the array and separate them with the string you pass to the separator parameter.

```
var ArrayEx = ['Zero'];

ArrayEx.push('One');
ArrayEx.push('Two');

alert(ArrayEx.join(', '));

// and

document.write(ArrayEx.join(', '));

// would both output: Zero, One, Two
```

For a new line, replace `', '` with `'\n'` in alerts and `'<br />'` in anything going to HTML; such as `document.write()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.write(ArrayEx.join('</br>'));
```

Comment: Providing an explanation in your answer will help your readers to learn.